# Using same views twice in two Fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a quiz app with two fragments, for the two quiz modes I have, within a ViewPager. For each fragment, in addition to other things, I dynamically create a list by inflating linearlayouts from XML within a while loop iterating through all the categories. This layout which contains this list is identical in both the modes, it is the rest of the fragment that is different, hence requiring two separate pages.

The problem therefore is that I do this costly process of inflating layouts twice, once within each fragment. I would like to do this only once and use it twice.

Two solutions I've considered:

- Using an adapter in the parent activity, accessing this through the
  fragments and subsequently using a ExpandableListView.

Problems:

1. I use checkboxes to select categories. The two fragments deal with clicks differently. With my limited knowledge I have no clue how achieve this. I understand that I can inflate a custom layout but then how do I set a listener in the fragment?
2. Some of my categories are grouped, others are standalone items. How do I remove the arrow in these items?

.

- Using an arraylist in the parent activity. Accessing this in each fragment and adding the layouts to the parent this way.

Problems:

1. Cannot do this as I'm adding the same view twice so I get an error as the specified child already has a parent. (IllegalStateException)

However this does mean I can easily access the CheckBoxes and iterate through settings oncheckedchangedlisteners

Thank you so much in advance :) If you require any more information or anything else just ask!

Comment: The two fragments are in a `ViewPager`?

Comment: Yes, I provide the ViewPager with a FragmentStatePageAdapter

Comment: Have you considered it from the other side, like having a switch to toggle between two modes (in your case it is `ViewPager`) and then change the single instance of your `ListView` to accommodate the requested mode (by adding or removing elements).

Comment: That was what I tried initially but the code became really complex as a lot of stuff needed to change which I couldn't just place in two large methods for the separate modes (and use an if/else statement) which is when I switched to the different fragments entirely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I dynamically create a list by inflating linearlayouts from XML
>   within a while loop iterating through all the categories.

This suggests a `ListView`.

> Using an arraylist in the parent activity. Accessing this in each
>   fragment and adding the layouts to the parent this way.

This solution will not work from the start, because you have the two fragments in a `ViewPager` which imposes a different behavior. If the fragments weren't in the `ViewPager` you could build a mechanism for storing those views in a list followed by dynamically detaching//attaching them from the fragments views. But storing the views in a list(and having them in memory all the time) plus the headache of managing their status isn't worth it.

> Using an adapter in the parent activity, accessing this through the
>   fragments and subsequently using a ExpandableListView.

Why use only one adapter and not two, one for each fragment(so they are independent)? I would also implement the adapter in the fragment itself.

> I use checkboxes to select categories. The two fragments deal with
>   clicks differently. With my limited knowledge I have no clue how
>   achieve this. I understand that I can inflate a custom layout but then
>   how do I set a listener in the fragment?

Not quite sure, but if you're talking about accessing the `CheckBoxe` from a "row" layout and having different behaviors on user actions based on the two fragments, you could very easy implement a base adapter class. That base adapter class will handle the common logic, but you'll also have an abstract method called on a `CheckBox` action(in the `OnCheckedChangeListener`). The two subclases(for the two fragments) of that base adapter will each implement that abstract method with their own logic independent from each other.

> Some of my categories are grouped, others are standalone items. How do
>   I remove the arrow in these items?

Like above, this can be done by implementing a smart adapter.

Comment: Thank you for your amazing reply! Literally went through everything perfectly. Would you be able to explain smart adapters or point me in the right direction?

Comment: @AndroidPenguin That adapter's implementation depends on how your current data looks. Here is a real basic adapter to see how you might handle different behavior on the same action https://gist.github.com/4572102